# get selected value in clean form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Trying to write custom validation for select field in the form. in template orm is displayed as:

```
<select id="id_myselect" name="myselect">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

forms.py

```
class SubmitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean_myselect(self):
        data=self.cleaned_data['myselect']
        if data == 'First':
            do something
        return data
```

Doesn't work I'm also try to get error on the page and I see that value is on the page.
Request information **POST** `myselect u'1'` but Local vars say `value myselect <Myselect: First>` Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare on the data value of the select not the sting.

As you have pointed out the value for `myselect` is `u'1'` so you need to compare against that and not the string representation.

```
class SubmitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean_myselect(self):
        data=self.cleaned_data['myselect']
        if data == 1: # 1 not "First"
            do something
        return data
```

Comment: Have you tried `pdb`/`ipdb` to see what `self.cleaned_data` contains

Comment: cleaned_data = {..., 'myselect':<Myselect: First>, ...}

Comment: Can you add your `Model` and the rest of the `Form` please